# Adding a new field to a existing model in django

Tags: django, model

I created a model in django. Migrated, then forgot I'd missed a field. I've added that field in (author) and now I am getting an error.

I've tried make migrations again but I get this...
gitpod /workspace/bookends (main) $ python3 manage.py makemigrations books
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'author' to books without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
Please select a fix:

1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
2. Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
   Select an option:

When I run the server in admin then click on books I get this error message.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jwk6y.png)

This is my model code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjLjn.png)

This is my admin.py code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyh0i.png)

Comment: this is not an error message, it just asks what to do. Did you read the prompt?

Comment: Thanks Willem, I'm a newbie so bare with me. I'm a little confused - it says it does not exist but it's in my model so do I need to tell it somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

Each time you modify your models since you made the last migration you need to make a new one. They are instructions on how your database should change.

In this case you probably have existing entries in a table that you want to add a new field to which means the migration doesnt know what to set as the value of the new field for the entries that didn't have it before. That's exactly what this error message is telling you.

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'author' to books without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows). Please select a fix:

Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)

Quit, and let me add a default in models.py Select an option:
```

This is a prompt asking you to choose a default value for the exisiting entries either in the cli or the code of models.py. You should follow it's insctructions or find a tutorial online if they still seem confusing.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to change the model so the value for this field is not required. You can add the following parameters for the field so that while doing the migration, it doesn't ask you for a default value:

`blank=True, null=True`

Be advised this is a workaround for something that is not a bug but a result of poor understanding of django.

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately didn't work - still have the same error

Comment: Maybe you need to add default value into the field empty string ?

Answer (score 0):

When you create a model and do the migrations, Django creates a table for that model in your database with the fields that are **currently** in your model. You may then create new objects of that model. Those objects have the initial fields filled with values. When you add a new field to your model, the older objects don't have that field. So when you try to add the new field to the old objects, Django does not know how to fill the new field for the old records. Should it leave them empty or should it fill them with a default value given by you?
You can either set a default value for the new field:

```py
new_field = models.SomeField(default=<your default value>)
```

This will fill the new field for older records with the default value.

OR since fields cannot just be left empty by default, you can set `null` and `blank` to True for the new field:

```
new_field = models.SomeField(null=True, blank=True)
```